# How can I have a process always running in background in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, tkinter

So I am making a pretty simple game in python mainly using tkinter. The game is this: you are a piece of paper and penicls are shooting off from the four main directions(up down left and right). You need to avoid the pencils, and when you get hit, you "die" and the game ends. So in the mainloop() I have the paper being binded to the arrow keys. I need to be able to shoot off the pencils from the 4 sides in the background. While the mainloop is happening the function pencilAttack() needs to be running continuously. I am working with Python 2.7.5 and an open to using(and probably will have to use) multithreading/processing . Here is all of my code, and it almost works, but not quite. IF you have any questions please feel free to ask. Thanks for the help!

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import *
import random
import time

def key(event):   #"IB" stands for in bounds, "OOB" stands for out of bounds
    right="IB"; left="IB"; top="IB"; bottom="IB"
    cntr1=0; cntr2=0; cntr3=0; cntr4=0
    while cntr1<len(C.find_overlapping(760,41,760,559)):
        if C.find_overlapping(760,41,760,559)[cntr1]==17:
            right="OOB"
            break
        cntr1+=1
    while cntr2<len(C.find_overlapping(40,41,40,559)):
        if C.find_overlapping(40,41,40,559)[cntr2]==17:
            left="OOB"    
            break
        cntr2+=1
    while cntr3<len(C.find_overlapping(41,40,759,40)):
        if C.find_overlapping(41,40,759,40)[cntr3]==17:
            top="OOB"
            break
        cntr3+=1
    while cntr4<len(C.find_overlapping(41,560,759,560)):
        if C.find_overlapping(41,560,759,560)[cntr4]==17:
            bottom="OOB"
            break
        cntr4+=1
    if (event.keysym == 'Right') and (right!="OOB"):
        C.move(paper, 20, 0)
    if (event.keysym == 'Left') and (left!="OOB"):
        C.move(paper, -20, 0)
    if (event.keysym == 'Up') and (top!="OOB"):
        C.move(paper, 0, -20)
    if (event.keysym == 'Down') and (bottom!="OOB"):
        C.move(paper, 0, 20)

def ifDead():
    cntr5=0
    bbox=C.bbox(17)
    while cntr5<len(C.find_overlapping(*bbox)):
        if C.find_overlapping(*bbox)[cntr5]>=18 and C.find_overlapping(*bbox)[cntr5]<=65:
            return True
        cntr5+=1

def pencilAttack():
    currentPencil=random.choice(allPencils)
    print currentPencil
    print type(currentPencil)
    cntr=0
    dead=False
    if currentPencil>=18 and currentPencil<=27:
        C.move(currentPencil, 70, 0)
        time.sleep(.5)
        while cntr<200:
            print cntr
            C.move(currentPencil, 5, 0)
            if ifDead()==True:
                dead=True
                break
            cntr+=1
        C.move(currentPencil, -1070, 0)         
    if currentPencil>=28 and currentPencil<=41:
        C.move(currentPencil, -70, 0)
        time.sleep(.5)
        while cntr<200:
            print cntr
            C.move(currentPencil, -5, 0)
            if ifDead()==True:
                dead=True
                break
            cntr+=1
        C.move(currentPencil, 1070, 0)  
    if currentPencil>=42 and currentPencil<=51:
        C.move(currentPencil, 0, 70)
        time.sleep(.5)
        while cntr<200:
            print cntr
            C.move(currentPencil, 0, 5)
            if ifDead()==True:
                dead=True
                break
            cntr+=1
        C.move(currentPencil, 0, -1070)  
    if currentPencil>=52 and currentPencil<=65:
        C.move(currentPencil, 0, -70)
        time.sleep(.5)
        while cntr<200:
            print cntr
            C.move(currentPencil, 0, -5)
            if ifDead()==True:
                dead=True
                break
            cntr+=1
        C.move(currentPencil, 0, 1070)

    if dead:
        top.destroy()

top = Tkinter.Tk()

C = Tkinter.Canvas(top, bg="light goldenrod", height=600, width=800)
#this below creates the background
C.create_line(760,41,760,559, fill="green")#light goldenrod
C.create_line(40,41,40,559, fill="blue")
C.create_line(41,40,759,40, fill="black")
C.create_line(41,560,759,560, fill="red")
C.create_line(0,100,1000,100, fill="deep sky blue")
C.create_line(0,150,1000,150, fill="deep sky blue")
C.create_line(0,200,1000,200, fill="deep sky blue")
C.create_line(0,250,1000,250, fill="deep sky blue")
C.create_line(0,300,1000,300, fill="deep sky blue")
C.create_line(0,350,1000,350, fill="deep sky blue")
C.create_line(0,400,1000,400, fill="deep sky blue")
C.create_line(0,450,1000,450, fill="deep sky blue")
C.create_line(0,500,1000,500, fill="deep sky blue")
C.create_line(0,550,1000,550, fill="deep sky blue")
C.create_line(0,600,1000,600, fill="deep sky blue")
C.create_line(75,0,75,1000, fill="red")

#this below creates the photos
rPencil = PhotoImage(file="H:\Computer Programming\Pencil right.gif")
lPencil = PhotoImage(file="H:\Computer Programming\Pencil left.gif")
tPencil = PhotoImage(file="H:\Computer Programming\Pencil top.gif")
bPencil = PhotoImage(file="H:\Computer Programming\Pencil bottom.gif")
paperpic = PhotoImage(file="H:\Computer Programming\paper2.gif")
paper = C.create_image(400,400, image = paperpic)


allPencils=[]
#ignore the one right under this
#lPencils-> -30x  rPencils-> 830x  tPencil-> -30y  bPencil-> 630y
#all these below create the pencils out of bounds to later be moved into place
pencil1=C.create_image(-100, 66, image = lPencil, tags="Lpencil");allPencils.append(pencil1)
pencil2=C.create_image(-100, 118, image = lPencil, tags="Lpencil");allPencils.append(pencil2)
pencil3=C.create_image(-100, 170, image = lPencil, tags="Lpencil");allPencils.append(pencil3)
pencil4=C.create_image(-100, 222, image = lPencil, tags="Lpencil");allPencils.append(pencil4)
pencil5=C.create_image(-100, 274, image = lPencil, tags="Lpencil");allPencils.append(pencil5)
pencil6=C.create_image(-100, 326, image = lPencil, tags="Lpencil");allPencils.append(pencil6)
pencil7=C.create_image(-100, 378, image = lPencil, tags="Lpencil");allPencils.append(pencil7)
pencil8=C.create_image(-100, 430, image = lPencil, tags="Lpencil");allPencils.append(pencil8)
pencil9=C.create_image(-100, 482, image = lPencil, tags="Lpencil");allPencils.append(pencil9)
pencil10=C.create_image(-100, 534, image = lPencil, tags="Lpencil");allPencils.append(pencil10)
pencil11=C.create_image(900, 534, image = rPencil, tags="Rpencil");allPencils.append(pencil11)
pencil12=C.create_image(900, 482, image = rPencil, tags="Rpencil");allPencils.append(pencil12)
pencil13=C.create_image(900, 430, image = rPencil, tags="Rpencil");allPencils.append(pencil13)
pencil14=C.create_image(900, 378, image = rPencil, tags="Rpencil");allPencils.append(pencil14)
pencil15=C.create_image(900, 326, image = rPencil, tags="Rpencil");allPencils.append(pencil15)
pencil16=C.create_image(900, 274, image = rPencil, tags="Rpencil");allPencils.append(pencil16)
pencil17=C.create_image(900, 222, image = rPencil, tags="Rpencil");allPencils.append(pencil17)
pencil18=C.create_image(900, 170, image = rPencil, tags="Rpencil");allPencils.append(pencil18)
pencil19=C.create_image(900, 118, image = rPencil, tags="Rpencil");allPencils.append(pencil19)
pencil20=C.create_image(900, 66, image = rPencil, tags="Rpencil");allPencils.append(pencil20)
pencil21=C.create_image(66, -100, image = tPencil, tags="Tpencil");allPencils.append(pencil21)
pencil22=C.create_image(118, -100, image = tPencil, tags="Tpencil");allPencils.append(pencil22)
pencil23=C.create_image(170, -100, image = tPencil, tags="Tpencil");allPencils.append(pencil23)
pencil24=C.create_image(222, -100, image = tPencil, tags="Tpencil");allPencils.append(pencil24)
pencil25=C.create_image(274, -100, image = tPencil, tags="Tpencil");allPencils.append(pencil25)
pencil26=C.create_image(326, -100, image = tPencil, tags="Tpencil");allPencils.append(pencil26)
pencil27=C.create_image(378, -100, image = tPencil, tags="Tpencil");allPencils.append(pencil27)
pencil28=C.create_image(430, -100, image = tPencil, tags="Tpencil");allPencils.append(pencil28)
pencil29=C.create_image(482, -100, image = tPencil, tags="Tpencil");allPencils.append(pencil29)
pencil30=C.create_image(534, -100, image = tPencil, tags="Tpencil");allPencils.append(pencil30)
pencil31=C.create_image(586, -100, image = tPencil, tags="Tpencil");allPencils.append(pencil31)
pencil32=C.create_image(638, -100, image = tPencil, tags="Tpencil");allPencils.append(pencil32)
pencil33=C.create_image(690, -100, image = tPencil, tags="Tpencil");allPencils.append(pencil33)
pencil34=C.create_image(742, -100, image = tPencil, tags="Tpencil");allPencils.append(pencil34)
pencil35=C.create_image(66, 700, image = bPencil, tags="Bpencil");allPencils.append(pencil35)
pencil36=C.create_image(118, 700, image = bPencil, tags="Bpencil");allPencils.append(pencil36)
pencil37=C.create_image(170, 700, image = bPencil, tags="Bpencil");allPencils.append(pencil37)
pencil38=C.create_image(222, 700, image = bPencil, tags="Bpencil");allPencils.append(pencil38)
pencil39=C.create_image(274, 700, image = bPencil, tags="Bpencil");allPencils.append(pencil39)
pencil40=C.create_image(326, 700, image = bPencil, tags="Bpencil");allPencils.append(pencil40)
pencil41=C.create_image(378, 700, image = bPencil, tags="Bpencil");allPencils.append(pencil41)
pencil42=C.create_image(430, 700, image = bPencil, tags="Bpencil");allPencils.append(pencil42)
pencil43=C.create_image(482, 700, image = bPencil, tags="Bpencil");allPencils.append(pencil43)
pencil44=C.create_image(534, 700, image = bPencil, tags="Bpencil");allPencils.append(pencil44)
pencil45=C.create_image(586, 700, image = bPencil, tags="Bpencil");allPencils.append(pencil45)
pencil46=C.create_image(638, 700, image = bPencil, tags="Bpencil");allPencils.append(pencil46)
pencil47=C.create_image(690, 700, image = bPencil, tags="Bpencil");allPencils.append(pencil47)
pencil48=C.create_image(742, 700, image = bPencil, tags="Bpencil");allPencils.append(pencil48)

C.pack()


top.bind_all('<Key>', key)
top.after(1000,pencilAttack)
top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use threads for this.  In almost all GUI frameworks, there's a single "event loop" thread that dispatches user input events and updates the UI.  If you try to update the UI from a different thread, nothing good will happen.  If you're lucky, the framework will catch you and raise an error telling you not to do this, otherwise you will just end up with difficult to debug race conditions.

Instead of `sleep` in your `pencilAttack` function, which will block the user interface thread, I would suggest performing the actions immediately, and then scheduling the `pencilAttack` function again with `top.after(500, pencilAttack)`.

As an aside, the only reason to use threads in a gui program is to perform heavy blocking work in the background, e.g. loading resources from a network or doing some kind of CPU intensive computations.  In this case, your GUI framework will provide methods for posting a function call from a background thread to the application thread.

Comment: @Isaac: I think it's important to note that `pencilAttack()` can reschedule itself to run again with the `top.after()` call at the end of the function (if it's not `dead`). It's also possible to update the display immediately after changes by using the universal widget method `widget.update_idletasks()`. Using it might be useful in the `pencilAttack()` function which appears to make potentially make many such changes.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! I used what both of u suggested and it works great! I just need to adjust some things, but then it should be complete! You guys rock!